# Change homepage to php script in cPanel

Tags: php, cpanel

My website's homepage doesn't show the page i want. The page I want to show up on my homepage  Fintessfans.me should be this page https://fitnessfans.me/Home/

Here's my file manager

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgdWw.png)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: changing the htpaccess file